# Using local apt repo with packages with same name different versions

Tags: apt

I've created local repo with two packages

these are the control files:

Package: package-a
Version: 1.0.0

Package: package-a
Version: 2.0.0

when I'm doing "sudo apt install package-a=1.0.0" or "sudo apt install package-a=2.0.0" it works great.

now I want a third package:

Package: test
Version: 1.0.0
Depends: package-a(=1.0.0)

If I'm trying "sudo apt install test" it doenst work, it gives me an error
unmet dependencies, package-a(2.0.0) is to be installed

What am I doing wrong? I want to use Depends on a different version

Answer (score 0):

The error message arose because the package `test` depends on `package_a=>1.0.0` but unfortunately, our "Advanced" package manager `apt` is trying to install the latest version of the package i.e `2.0.0`. The package `test` is programmed to work only with the `package_a=>1.0.0`. To fix:

- You can use the `aptitude` package manager.
- You can install the version manually.

To install using aptitude package manager:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aptitude 
sudo aptitude -f install test
```

Press `n` unless it proposes the correct solution.

To install manually using `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install package_a=1.0.0
sudo apt install test
```

This will successfully install `test`.

**N.B**: APT always install the latest version of the package; You can't have more that 2 version of the same package because they may cause file conflicts.

Comment: But its not always install the lastest version, thats why I can install with “sudo apt install package-a=1.0.0”

Comment: @asafanter unless you specify a version with the `=`, it would install the latest version.

Comment: @asafanter If my answer worked for you, you can hit the tick mark near the vote count to accept this answer.

Comment: But I specified the = in the depends field

Comment: @asafanter Sorry, which field are you talking about?

Comment: look at my question, “test” package is depends on package-a(=1.0.0)

Comment: @asafanter Seems like you are misunderstanding something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133849/discussion-between-asaf-anter-and-someone).